# Execute Timer Events of another Blueprint from the C++ UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-4, events, timer, delegates

I am having problem and it's about a week now that I still can't figure out how to get it right.

It seems that I can't run any functions from the blueprints that contain timers at all.

I have a Datatable full of details of each functions that will executed according to its key input and the owner of the functions. 
[image]

The ordinary functions and custom events executed well but will stopped at a timer.
[image]

This is the code that I have made so far. I added the matching functions string into the delegate with its Owner which is the obj, and it will executed on key input.

p.s: Ignore the error, Intellisense was messing me up

[image]

I saw the error regarding the world not found here,
[image]

but I'm not sure if that is the case since other functions without any timer inside can execute well. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The function that you want to call is in BP or in C++  ?

Comment: It's in BP, the Tooled custom event, it will printed 'Hello' but it will skip the Set Timer function. I dont know why

Comment: I see nothing plugged in to `Object Pin` there in set timer func - maybe you should put a `self reference` there ?

Comment: I did it just now but still no changes ((

Comment: In your ToadBlue behaviour tree do you pass it as a self to some function that expects to get a world context ?

Comment: So you are calling the `tooled` event for C to execute a timer in BP ?
Why don't you just execute the timer from C++ ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You mean create my own custom Timer? Other programmers in my team are more comfortable with blueprints so I wanted to make this system more friendly to them.

Comment: You can also call a BP function from the C++ timer if you need so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved it. I have to point the UObject to AActor by using

`UGameplayStatics GetActorOfClass(this, ActorClass)` and apparently the `obj` was pointed to the wrong blueprint object in the game, but I read somewhere that it is not good to use GetActorOfClass too many times, but for now I'll just use this before I find another better solutions.